# Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: <div id="ctools-modal">

Tags: 7, views, ajax, chaos-tool-suite

I want to display a form in CTool modal dialog, but failing badly.

When I click link to show modal form, ajax request is started:

POST http://drupal.dev/my_mod/arg1/ajax/arg3

and returns:

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: <div id="ctools-modal"> 
<div class="ctools-modal-dialog">      <div class="modal-content">    
<div class="modal-header">          <button type="button"
class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
<h4 id="modal-title" class="modal-title">&nbsp;</h4>        </div>    
<div id="modal-content" class="modal-body">        </div>      </div> 
</div>  </div>
```

I tried to click different link, but gets an error:

> TypeError: Drupal.CTools.Modal.modal is undefined

Code:

```
function my_mod_menu() {
  return array(
    'my_mod/%/%ctools_js/%' => array(
      'title' => 'Entity Modal Edit',
      'page arguments' => array(1,3),
      'page callback' => 'my_mod_modal_page_callback',
      'access callback' => 'my_mod_modal_access_callback',
      'access arguments' => array(1,2,3),
      'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    ),
  );
}

function my_mod_modal_page_callback($entity_type, $id) {
  ctools_include('modal');
  ctools_include('ajax');
  ctools_modal_add_js();

  $form_state['user'] = user_load($id);
  $output = ctools_modal_form_wrapper('my_mod_form', $form_state);
  ctools_modal_render('Edit', $output);
  exit;  
}
```

I'm creating my edit link in custom views_field_handler:

```
class my_mod_handler_field_links extends views_handler_field {

  function init(&$view, &$options) {
    parent::init($view, $options);

    if (! isset(self::$some_property)) {
      ctools_include('modal');
      ctools_include('ajax');
      ctools_modal_add_js
    }
  }



  function render($values) {

    $edit_link = array(
      'href' => 'my_mod_ctools/some_value1/nojs/some_other_value',
      'title' => t('edit'),
      'attributes' => array('class' => array('mymod-ctools-links', 'ctools-use-modal', 'use-ajax')),
    );

    $links[] = $edit_link;

    $build = array(
      '#prefix' => '<div class="mymod-ctools-links-wrapper">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
      '#theme' => 'links',
      '#links' => $links,
    return drupal_render($build);
  }

  function query() {}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had using jQuery 1.9. I changed it to 2.1 and the problem is solved (jquery_update module)